# widehat not fully working with sans serif fonts

Tags: math-mode, accents, sans-serif, yhmath

I'm using a sans serif font. Weirdly, widehat doesn't seems to work well with sans serif fonts (I tested with different sans serif fonts (defaut latex one, cmbright, kurier, iwona) and the problem is the same for each one): for some letters the hat is correctly located above the letter, but for smoe other ones the hat is shifted towards the left.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, yhmath}

\begin{document}
Working: $\widehat{H}$

Not working: $\widehat{C}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Does anyone knows how to fix widehat to work correctly with all sans serif letters?

Comment: Exactly which latex installation are you using here? For me this MWE does **not** give the image you provide. I get the correct output with the MWE using TeXLive 2021

Comment: I'm using Miktex 21.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: No problem with MiKTeX 21.8. Did you try updating first?

Comment: I just did, it seems to have solved the issue. Not sure why however...

Comment: why `\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}` ?

Comment: I was just trying different things here and there to solve the issue. I went back to T1.

Comment: I tried your code with TeX Live binaries from 2013 to 2021 and the output is always as expected.